# Get specific version macports dependencies

Tags: macports

Some ports have several versions installed, for example:

```
sqlite3 @3.7.17_0
sqlite3 @3.8.0_0 (active)
```

How do I get dependencies per **each of them**?

```
$ port deps sqlite3@3.7.17_0
Full Name: sqlite3 @3.8.0.2_0
Library Dependencies: libedit
$ port echo depof:sqlite3 and version:3.7.17_0
$ port echo depof:sqlite3 and version:@3.7.17_0
$
```

No success at the moment.

P.S.: wanted the `dependencies` tag for this question.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this info?

Comment: @Mark, I want to make a simple Ruby script to draw me a dependencies tree to find if I can deinstall smth useless for me.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like either a bug or a limitation with the `deps` command to me. A quick look in the [MacPorts Guide](http://guide.macports.org/#using.port.deps), and `port help deps` doesn't specify any such limitation, though that's not very conclusive.

I'm not sure if you should be able to see dependencies for different **versions**, though I can definitely see different dependencies for different **variants**.

I have two versions of `boost` installed (note the different python variants, but same version):

```
% port installed boost
The following ports are currently installed:
  boost @1.54.0_0+no_single+no_static+python27 (active)
  boost @1.54.0_0+no_single+no_static+python33
```

And I can check their dependencies independently by referencing them as `portname@version+variants` (version & variants being optional):

```
% port deps boost @1.54.0_0+no_single+no_static+python27
Full Name: boost @1.54.0_0+no_single+no_static+python27
Library Dependencies: zlib, expat, bzip2, libiconv, icu, python27

% port deps boost @1.54.0_0+no_single+no_static+python33
Full Name: boost @1.54.0_0+no_single+no_static+python33
Library Dependencies: zlib, expat, bzip2, libiconv, icu, python33
```

But I also have two versions of `glib2` and `pango` installed at present:

```
% port installed glib2 pango
The following ports are currently installed:
  glib2 @2.36.4_0
  glib2 @2.38.0_0 (active)
  pango @1.34.1_1+x11
  pango @1.36.0_0+x11 (active)
```

Yet, likewise, cannot see the deps of the inactive versions:

```
% port deps glib2 @2.36.4_0
Full Name: glib2 @2.38.0_1
Extract Dependencies: xz
Build Dependencies:   libxml2
Library Dependencies: gettext, libiconv, zlib, libffi, perl5

% port deps pango @1.34.1_1+x11
Full Name: pango @1.36.0_0+x11
Extract Dependencies: xz
Build Dependencies:   pkgconfig
Library Dependencies: glib2, cairo, gobject-introspection, harfbuzz, Xft2
```

Both show the newer (active) version rather than the older one, even with the `--index` argument to deps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
Macports dependencies are between ports and not versions.

Only one port used at a time that is the active one
Variants and versions of a port can depend on different ports. But different ports and/or variants cannot depend on variants see the Macports [FAQ](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ#dependonvariant)

Comment: There seems to be some difference for *versions* and *variants*, so it may not be quite that simple...? I'm able to see different dependencies for two different installations of boost (same version, different variants). See my answer for specifics.

Comment: I think the variants can depend on different librariess/binaries etc but they cannot depend on a specific variant of a library